# JSON - Display only certain data in php

Tags: php, json

This is my json data as an array, and it is in the file `data.json`, I tried to parse the data using php, but I am not able show the result using a for loop.

```
array (
  'data' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3222,
      'b' => 3,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3221,
      'b' => 3,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'a' => 2215,
      'b' => 2,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'a' => 2214,
      'b' => 2,
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3218,
      'b' => 2,
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3217,
      'b' => 3,
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3216,
      'b' => 3,
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'a' => 1235,
      'b' => 1,
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'a' => 1234,
      'b' => 1,
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'a' => 1233,
      'b' => 1,
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      'a' => 3213,
      'b' => 3,
    )
)
```

I want to display only the data, which is "b=3" which contains the maximum value of "a".

Here is my code, which displays all the results of "a" as a string. All the data is shown as a list.

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('data.json');

    $data = json_decode($json,true);

    $q = $data['data'];

    $length = count($q);

    for ($i = 0; $i<$length ; $i++){
        if ($q[$i]['b']==3){
            $pc = $q[$i]['a'];
            echo $pc;
            echo "<br>";    
        }
    }
```

This is not the result I was expected.

Comment: `which contains the maximum value of "a"` so where do you take the maximum?

Comment: @vivek_23 Sorry my bad English. I was trying to say, I want only to see the maximum value of "a" from all the arrays which is "b=3", i can not use php max() function inside that loop, which gives an error.

Comment: [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) should work. Anyways, you got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this could be to check the current value of `$pc` against the latest value;
If that is higher, then overwrite it:

```
$q = $data['data'];

$length = count($q);
$max = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i<$length ; $i++){
    if ($q[$i]['b']==3){
        $pc = $q[$i]['a'];
        if ($pc > $max) {
            $max = $pc;
        }
    }
}
echo $max; //3222
```

Another option could be to use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
$result = max(array_map(function($x){
    if($x['b'] === 3) return $x['a'];
    }, $q
));

echo $result; //3222
```